# Java: Reading lines from a file when not all lines have a new line

Tags: java, string, file, java.util.scanner

I'm working on a program that opens a data file and reads the file line by line using a while loop to store data in a binary search tree. My only problem though is I'm not sure how to handle the loop condition, as the last line of the file does not have a new line character. I usually use hasNextLine() with a scanner for reading through a file, but this throws errors in my program, and I can't use hasNext() because I need to grab the entire line and not just pieces of it. What would be the best way to go about this?

```
    public static BinaryTree getInventory(BinaryTree tree, Scanner input) {
    String line, title = "";
    int available = -1, rented = -1, comma = 0;
    boolean quote = true;

    // While not the end of file
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        line = input.nextLine();

        for (int i = 1; i < line.length(); i++) {
            if (line.charAt(i) == '"') {
                title = line.substring(1, i);
                comma = i + 1;
                quote = false;
                i++;
            } 
            else if (line.charAt(i) == ',' && !quote) {
                available = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(comma + 1, i - 1));
                comma = i;
                i++;
            } 
            else if (i + 1 == line.length()) {
                rented = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(comma + 1, i));
            }

        }
        tree.insert(new Node(title,available,rented));
    }
    return tree;
}
```

Comment: Please present some code

Comment: Please show your current implementation.

Comment: if you use BufferedReader  (you can read a file and create a BufferedReader if you want to), then you can use lines() method that gives you a Stream<String> corresponding every line of the file, see if it helps get through this.

Comment: @YoungMillie Sorry, added my current code.

Comment: Are you sure about the condition in the for-loop `for (int i = 1; i < line.length(); i++) `. Thus `i < line.length()`? Shouldn't it be `i <= line.length()`?

Comment: @YoungMillie I coded it that way because I know the first character in the input will always be a quotation mark, so I just skip the first character

Comment: Okay that help more to understand what is up there, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the need of `hasNext()` by catching `NoSuchElementException`. Also given the structure of your file (which seems to be `"title",XX,YY`) you an avoid looping over line characters with a code like this

```
try {
    while (true) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        int rdquo = line.indexOf('"', 1);
        String title = line.substring(1, rdquo);
        String[] avail = line.substring(rdquo+2).split(",");
        tree.insert(new Node(title, Integer.parseInt(avail[0]) , Integer.parseInt(avail[1]));
    }
} catch (NoSuchElementException reachedEndOfFile) { }
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much!

Comment: This approach has the added benefit of supporting titles that contain commas.

Comment: @Sergio As a matter of style and legibility, it's best to avoid deliberately triggering an Exception when nothing abnormal happened.  In this case, you can replace `while (true)` with `while (input.hasNextLine())` and eliminate the try-catch.

Comment: I agree that I wouldn't normally throw an catch and exception on purpose for flow control reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer should solve your problem just fine, but I think it's worth pointing something out so you (or people learning from your post) correctly understand how Scanner works.

Given an input source like `Line 1\nLine 2`, where Line 2 does not end in a newline character, the following code will print both lines without throwing any errors.

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(input.nextLine());
}
```

This will also print both lines.

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(input.nextLine());
}
```

Given your example code, I think it's most likely that one of your titles contained a comma, which would lead to Integer.parseInt trying to parse some text that isn't an integer.  When asking for help troubleshooting code that throws an error, it's helpful to share the exception and possibly a stack trace.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry, still a little new to this forum. It was actually me speculating that there could be a comma inside the title because I don't know what the input is going to be. I'll make sure to include any possible exceptions in the future!